Is there an ESV Bible platform that helps organize your passage bookmarks in multiple lists?
I am looking for an ESV Bible website that allows you to save your bookmarks in a more flexible way. I find that I usually bookmark certain passages but I'm always challenged in not being able to find those bookmarks. Most Bible apps/sites give you all of your bookmarks in a long list, typically from most recent to oldest, which does not work well for me.
Is there a platform that lets you organize said notes like a file directory?
I have already looked at YouVersion, BibleGateway, esv.org, but they don't have the feature.

Welcome to C.SE. Does it have to be a website, or are you open to a smartphone app or a desktop app?

Logos is a full-featured Bible study app and can certainly help you organize your bookmarks, using its Passage List feature (see explanation and video demo here).
The Desktop App version is the most full featured, but I have confirmed that the Mobile App version (from Google / Apple app store) also has the Passage List feature.  Its Web App version which you can access here doesn't appear to have it, but it DOES have the Notes Tool feature which you can adapt by creating a "highlight" for each of your bookmark, and then organizing those highlights in multiple notebooks (see explanation and video demo here).
Logos works by granting you access to resources when you purchase one or more Logos Editions.  But they also offer a Free Edition which includes the ESV Bible as well as a few other translations and free Bible study resources such as Faithlife Study Bible, Lexham Bible Dictionary, Logos Bible Maps, and Hebrew and Greek Reverse Interlinears that the app engine seamlessly link to any translations you prefer, including ESV.
To get started, create a Logos account (which is free of charge) under which your notebooks (which contain the highlights as well as regular notes), passage lists, sermons, and documents are saved and can be synced across all your installations, whether it's Desktop App, Mobile App, or Web App.

This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Glad it works out for you.  Welcome to C.SE.
